# Oracle Sql Query to Return a Row when there is no Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which displays sum of employees in a particular group (A1,B1..etc) and in a specifc department.

The problem is when there is no data for a specific department at a specific date then that row with the department name is not displayed at all and I want the query to display all the rows/department names even if they have data in it or not. It should display '0' in such a case.

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(dept_name,'NA') ),'TOTAL') AS Department,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS A1,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS B1,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI','XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS TOTAL
FROM emp e
WHERE 
dept_name IN('IT','FI','ACC')
AND e.transaction_date          = trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY rollup(COALESCE(dept_name,'NA'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should read about outer joins.

Comment: Left joins only work when there is an available table.  Is there a department table?  Is there a foreign key from emp to department?

Comment: No, there is just 1 table and that is 'emp'.

Answer (score 1):

Start from `departments`(you should have something like that... ) and do a left join:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(d.dept_name,'NA') ),'TOTAL') AS Department,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS A1,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS B1,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI','XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS TOTAL
FROM departments d
left join emp e on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
WHERE 
d.dept_name IN('IT','FI','ACC')
AND e.transaction_date          = trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY rollup(COALESCE(d.dept_name,'NA'));
```

If you don't have departments you can left join with dual in this manner:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(e.dept_name,'NA') ),'TOTAL') AS Department,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS A1,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS B1,
  SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN ( emp_group IN ('ABC','CDE','EFG','GHI','XYZ'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS TOTAL
FROM (select 'IT' as dept_name from dual union all 
      select 'FI' from dual union all
      select 'ACC' from dual) d
left join emp e on d.dept_name = e.dept_name
WHERE 
  e.transaction_date          = trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY rollup(COALESCE(e.dept_name,'NA'));
```

Comment: No, there is just 1 table and that is 'emp'. How can I achieve it with 1 table now? Thanks.

Comment: I tried the above query with left join on the same table and on the dual table, but it displays the same result as before.